# Amount of milk in a macchiato beverage

Tags: espresso, milk

What is the correct amount of milk to put into a macchiato? Does it depend on the amount of espresso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Italian word *macchiato* literally means "marked" or "stained" (related to the word "immaculate" [[1](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=immaculate&allowed_in_frame=0)]), so really it is an indication to add a small quantity of the "staining" liquid, be it espresso or milk.

A *caffe macchiato* (also called *espresso macchiato*) is a shot of espresso (or two) with a "stain" of steamed milk and sometimes a little foam to indicate there is milk hiding under the espresso's *crema*.

A *latte macchiato* is the opposite concept, where steamed milk is "stained" by a shot of espresso.

As with any of these drinks, the variations are endless, so recipes and even ratios would be specific to a particular cafe.

Answer (score 1):

This question will largely be based off of the individual tastes of the person consuming the drink.

From my experience as a barista, typically for every ~2 ounces (Double Shot) of espresso, you'll want about 2-3 spoonfuls of milk froth.

Of course, some people enjoy more or less.

Comment: I think a lot of coffee questions might be based on individual tastes, but perhaps the question should be re-worded to ask how much milk a barista is typically trained to put into a macchiato?